# Differentiate for D, L, σ, and T

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am currently getting a primer in Calculus before taking some classes this fall and am reading Calculus Made Easy by Silvanus P. Thompson. It's a great and very readable book so far. I'm doing the exercises for chapter two on differentiation with constants and can't seem to work through this one problem. The problem is this:

The frequency $n$ of vibration of a string of diameter $D$, length $L$ and specific gravity $σ$, stretched with a force $T$, is given by
$$n=\frac1{DL}\sqrt{\frac{gT}{\pi\sigma}}.$$
Find the rate of change of the frequency when $D$, $L$, $σ$, and $T$ are varied singly. I know that I am supposed to find $dn/dD$, $dn/dL$, etc. I am, however, unsure how to approach differentiating for a single variable. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks everyone.

Comment: Just remind yourself that all the other letters are constants, as is $g$.

Comment: Thanks for responding Ted. It looks like the constants can be "ignored" for this variable. If I am right, I have tried several different things and still haven't come up with the right answer.

Comment: Well, let's see an example of what you've done. Make sure I edited correctly.

Comment: It's beautiful. And sure, just a moment. Looks like I need to read over some instructions for posting correctly.

Comment: Here is where I get with the problem: $$n+dn=\frac1{(D + dD)L} $$ I simply cannot find out where to go from here assuming I have approached it correctly so far.

Comment: No, you can't just stick $d$ in front of variables. You have rules for derivatives. For example, if I give you $V=\frac{nRT}p$, then you'd have (fixing everybody else) $\frac{dV}{dT}=\frac{nR}p$ and $\frac{dV}{dp}=-\frac{nRT}{p^2}$.

Comment: I see. It looks like my confusion is when differentiating the bottom of a fraction. I do not understand how the fraction is now negative with a variable squared as the denominator. If you could describe how you got that it would help tremendously in solving the rest of the problem. I really appreciate your help on this Ted.

Comment: You need to look at examples in the book. Surely they've shown how to take the derivative of $1/x$. I'm not going to be sble to teachbyou a calculus class here in these comments!:)

Comment: I completely understand. It is odd though I haven't taken the derivative 1/x. I will do more research and figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TedShifrin CME introduces the "y+dy = x+dx" strategy on p17 and relies on the strategy right up to the page this problem is on, offering no other way to get to the answer. I think this is using infinitesimals? I'm still curious how it would be done in this case.

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi: I'm not a huge fan of the "infinitesimal" approach, but to follow up on what Blake started above, solve for $dn = (n+dn)-n = \dfrac1{(D+dD)L} - \dfrac1{DL} = \dfrac{D-(D+dD)}{D(D+dD)L} = \dfrac{-dD}{D(D+dD)L} = \dfrac{-dD}{D^2L}$ (plus stuff that is small compared to $dD$, so we ignore it — in other words, we ignore the $dD$ in the denominator because it goes to $0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To take a derivative with respect to one variable just treat the others as constants. Taking the derivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ it's simpler to look at it as $x^{-1}$. Since the derivative of anything is $nx^{n-1}$ you can see that you get $\frac{1}{x^2}$.

In your case all you have to do is break the $\frac{1}{D}$ away from the other stuff, which is just constants.

Also, one thing I always do that makes stuff like this easier is change an equation like that to $$n = \frac{1}{D}(\frac{gT}{\sigma \pi})^{1/2}$$ or if you want to fo even further $$n = D^{-1}(\frac{gT}{\sigma \pi})^{1/2}$$
which might make it easier to see the exponents you are working with. Taking a derivative $(\frac{dn}{dD})$ of that should get you:
$$(\frac{dn}{dD}) = -D^{-2}(\frac{gT}{\sigma \pi})^{1/2}$$

One of the interesting properties of fractions and taking derivatives is that the exponents go up, not down. Another funky thing that happens is when you start doing integrals because the integral of 1/x is ln(x). But that's another story.

EDIT: just realized i had the equation wrong myself but fixed it.

Comment: Many thanks Jesse. I had done a bit of research and had done the above and solved for both L and D. T on the other hand had me a bit confused. Would I take $\frac1{2}$ and apply the power rule to $T$ making it $T^(\frac-1{2}$ ?

Comment: That was supposed to be $T^{-1/2}$. Sorry for the multiple edits.